# Best way to integrate modulus functions?

Tags: integration

Consider 
$ \int_{-2}^{3} |1-x^2| dx$

if we find part of domains where function  is positive, then we write

$ \int_{-2}^{-1} (x^2 -1) dx + \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)dx + \int_{1}^{3} (x^2 -1) dx$

But this is very painful to evaluate, is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any direct faster way, but you could use symmetry in the particular functions to reduce the effort.

Comment: eg. here $=2\int_0^2|1-x^2|\,dx+\int_2^3 |1-x^2|\,dx$

Comment: Good idea! hmm I am looking for something faster

Comment: since modulus functions aren't strictly smoooth (continuous differential) and are actually a nice way of representing piecewise functions there shouldn't be an easy way to represent the integral of one like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than five months of this question sitting in the back of my mind, I have finally come to a 'fast way' to solve such questions.

Observe that the function we are integrating is even and hence it is deal to split over even bound,

$$  \int_{-2}^{3} |1-x^2| dx = \int_{-2}^2  |1-x^2|dx + \int_2^3 |1-x^2| dx$$

Now, $$ \int_{-2}^2 |1-x^2|dx = 2 \int_0^2 |1-x^2|dx$$

Hence,

$$  \int_{-2}^3 |1-x^2|  dx =2 \int_0^2 |1-x^2|dx+ \int_2^3 |1-x^2| dx$$

Now, notice the definition of our function,

$$ q = \begin{cases} x^2-1, x>1\\ 1-x^2, 0<x<1 \end{cases}$$

Hence our integral now becomes,

$$ \int_{-2}^3 |1-x^2| dx = 2 [\int_0^1 1-x^2 dx + \int_1^2 x^2 -1 dx ] + \int_2^3 x^2 -1 dx $$

Call $f=1-x^2$ and the anti derivative of it as $F$, then by fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$ \int_{-2}^3 |1-x^2| dx = 2 \left[- [F(1) - F(0)] + F(2) - F(1) \right] + F(3) - F(2)= -4F(1) +2F(0)  + F(3) - F(2) = F(3) +F(2)- 4F(1) + 2F(0) = F(3) +F(2)- 4F(1) $$

Which is a much simpler task. This method is a much more efficient one only if you do the parts it consists of in your head.

Tl;dr: Use even -odd property, split the integral, use fundamental theorem , drop off terms which have zeros.

Comment: Why do so much donkey work? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%7C1-x%5E2%7C+dx+from+x%3D-2+to+3

Comment: There is a timed exam in India called JEE, in that the questions are of mcq type. It helps to be able to solve some questions fast so you have time to think of the other ones.

Comment: looks like if you know which questions are time wasters then you save time for questions that can be done faster. this type of question is compound question, first determining the negative values and flipping then add 4 integrals, good time waster. the link shows how to it